# Css assign multiple style blocks for one class

Tags: css

**Can I wrap a class (or id) around styling to apply it to elements only in that class?** 

For example, I have :

```
 .title {
   color: #000;
  }
  .block {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 90%;
  }
```

I'd like to create a different design for these things, if they are in a specific class. I know You can do it like so:

```
.specific_class .title{
   color: #fff;
}
```

But then I have to add it to each block. Can I do something like this?

```
.specific_class{
      .title {
        color: #fff;
      }
      .block {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .wrapper {
        width: 91%;
      }
}
```

..just to assign different styles to work, if elements are in a specific class.
(I know the last example doesn't actually work). 
I have a lot of these little blocks, so one "wrapping" would work and look a lot better than copy/pasting `.specific_class` in front of each one. 
 
I'd like to apologize, if such question exists. I just couldn't find the correct words and find the solution, but there probably is a question like mine.

Comment: You can use http://sass-lang.com/ or http://lesscss.org/ to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in regular CSS. However, you might be interested in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com), a CSS preprocessor that allows you to [write nested rules](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_rules) (amongst other things) and compile them down to regular CSS.

Comment: Yeah. I thought so. I just wanted an outside opinion. Hoped there is some magic trick. Crap, oh well... Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Yeah, we all have those "Why in the world isn't this built in?!" moments.